# current timestamp = tomorrow

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have recently changed my server time zone to `America/New_York`.

The problem is when I run my php/mysql script to add rows into the database with default: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it adds the date as tomorrow instead of today.

Then when tomorrow rolls over at midnight on my server, the dates go back to yesterday?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL uses its own time zone settings and PHP uses its own time zone settings.

Make sure when you configure your PHP time zone settings, set the same time zone settings for MySQL as well.

Oh and by the way, Timestamp data type in MySQL doesn't store time zone information, If you supply timezone to MySQL when writing to this field, MySQL will convert it to UTC based on its timezone settings.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` -- perform this in mysql console

If it gives incorrect result - change the mysql server timezone explicitly in config file:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html